# #define directive in C Giving ambiguous answer

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SQR(x) x*x
int main()
{
    printf("%d",225/SQR(15));
    return 0;
}
```

The output to this code is 225. I'm unable to understand as what really is happening here.
If I use `#define SQR(x) (x*x)` Then it works fine which i get as we are supposed to use parentheses if we have an expression with some operator.
But in the previous case I'm not clear as to what is really happening. Why is the answer 225?

Comment: Remember, macros do simple substitution: `225/SQR(15)` -> `225/15*15` -> `(225/15)*15`

Comment: oh thank you. Got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Macros do substitution only(done before compilation of the code).

Therefore the following line

```
printf("%d",225/SQR(15));
```

after substitution will become:

```
printf("%d",225/15*15);
```

now this expression evaluates to 225 (basic maths : divide first -> 15*15, then multiply -> 225)

using brackets solves your problem(then it becomes 225/(15*15)).
:)

Answer (score 3):

`#define` macros aren't functions - they are just macros, text replacement. If you take the expression `225/SQR(15)` and replace `SQR` with `15*15`, you'll get `225/15*15`, and since `/` and `*` have the save precedence and are left associative - `255/15*15 = 255`.

Comment: ... same precedence and they're left associative.

Comment: @melpomene good point, thanks. I've edited it in.

Answer (score 2):

Notice the steps

> 1) 225/SQR(15)
>
> 2) 225/15*15

**Division executed first due to precedence**

> 3) 15*15
>
> 4) 225

Answer (score 0):

See `#define` as a text replacement tool in a text editor; it works the same way (well, almost).

Here are two rules you might want to follow in order to avoid this kind of errors:

1. When working with macros, always use parentheses for each "variable" given to the macro and for the whole result.

Example:

```
#define MAX(a, b) ((a) > (b) ? (a) : (b))
```

2. When you have an unexpected behavior, use the command line tool `cpp` (c preprocessor) to see how the macro is actually interpreted.

Example:

```
$ cpp main.c
```